# Nice collection of local meromorphic functions generates a divisor

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry, meromorphic-functions

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface and let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be an open covering. Suppose that on any $U_\alpha$ we have a meromorphic function $g_\alpha$ such that $\frac{g_\alpha}{g_\beta}$ is holomorphic and invertible on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.

For any point $x\in X$ we can define the **order at $x$ of the collection $g=\{g_\alpha\}$** simply as:
$$ord_x(g):= ord_x(g_{\alpha})\quad \text{if }\; x\in U_\alpha$$

This number is well defined thanks to the property on intersections.

> I don't understand why there are only finitely many  points such that
>   $ord_x(g)\neq 0$. The open sets $U_{\alpha}$ are not compact, so
>   $g_{\alpha}$ can have infinitely many points of nonzero order on
>   $U_\alpha$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every zero must have a neighborhood around it that contains no other zeros; otherwise the zero set would contain a limit point, which is not possible for meromorphic functions.  Taking all these sets together with the complement of the zero set ( which is also open ), we get an open cover of the compact Riemann surface.  This cover must have a finite subcover, which shows there are only finitely many zeroes